# receive packet from device is not working as expected

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ip, communication

Here is my configuration

```
my PC IP     :192.168.1.57   subnetmask : 255.255.255.0
my device IP :73.83.1.57     subnetmask : 255.255.255.0
```

i am successfully able to send packet from my pc to device but not able to send packet from device to pc (have checked in wire shark but it show only PC->device packet transmission flow )

Now i have added one more IP like device ip family in PC (73.83.1.60) then successfully able to two way communication.same works in reverse order means i have set my device IP as 192.168.1.58.

So is there any rules like both IP must belongs to same IP family?
because sub net mask in both are same. so issue is IP.

Any one have idea? is it correct network behavior? can i solve it without making same IP family.?

Comment: Are the devices on the same LAN, or jumping via some router?

Comment: Please ask this kind of questions on server-fault as you question is basically a network-topology one and not a programming one.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes both are on same LAN

Comment: @PatrickB.You are right will that in my mind next time. but you say this is not programming one.So can you comment for this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465630/computer-networking-arp-point-of-the-icmp-echo-packets?rq=1 also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286426/two-hosts-with-different-subnets-on-layer-2-switch-why-does-this-work?rq=1 also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242777/respond-arp-request-from-a-different-subnet?rq=1

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic for SO. Sorry JKB; you're right in that more cleanup of SO is required. Remember that there is always [ServerFault.com](http://serverfault.com/about) for networking/infrastructure related questions and that is the right place for them. If this had more to do with your C code and less to do with the network configuration this would be a valid SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using both IPs on the same LAN they should be on the same subnet ex:
11.1.1.1/24 can ping 11.1.1.44/24  but it can't ping 11.1.2.2/24 ( different subnets)

In WAN not necessary, for example 192.168.1.1 can ping 72.1.1.1 ,, but 72.1.1.1 can't ping 192.168.1.1 because this ip is private and when it leaves the LAN it becomes real ip because of NAT (Network Address Translation)